# What's the difference between adding Nodes to a List manually vs using an addNode method?

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I noticed that it was possible to use two different methods to insert a node in a linked list. Some people use the following lines of code:

```
Node head = newNode(3);
head.next = newNode(5);
head.next.next = newNode(8);
```

With the following method:

```
static Node newNode(int data)
{
    Node new_node = new Node();
    new_node.data = data;
    new_node.next = null;
    return new_node;
}
```

While other people use the following lines of code:

```
sList.addNode(2);  
sList.addNode(2);  
sList.addNode(3);
```

With the following method:

```
public void addNode (int data) {
        Node newnode = new Node(data);
        if (head == null) {
            head = newnode;
            tail = newnode;
        } else {
            tail.next = newnode;
            tail = newnode;
        }
        size++;
    }
```

I don't know when to use the first technique and when to use the second one.

Comment: Hey Sarah, Would you like to show the contents of the newNode method as well just like you're shown addNode? Or is that a typo and you meant to type new Node()

Comment: No it was not a typo, and I can add the newNode method.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your inquiry. Could you remove the `size++` and `Node tail = head.next.next;` I added? I would do the edit however our site's edit queue is full. :] 
@SarahLep

Comment: You have received two answers... could you give feed back to them?

Answer (score 0):

In high performance applications this is preferred:

```java
Node head = new Node(3);
size++;
head.next = new Node(5);
size++;
head.next.next = new Node(8);
size++;

Node tail = head.next.next;
```

As doing so avoids making an additional method call which can have an overhead if it's not inlined. Furthermore the `addNode` method contains additional checks which are completely avoided doing it this way. The downside is it's up to the programmer to ensure they remember to give the List a head, tail, and increment the size as nodes are added.

**Summary: This uses less computing resources but takes more programmer effort. It makes the code more difficult to understand.**

---

If this List class is for a library, then the `addNode` method is the way to go:

```java
sList.addNode(2);  
sList.addNode(2);  
sList.addNode(3);
```

The user of the class will call `addNode` and the method will take care of everything for them, they don't have to ensure there's a List head, tail, and that the size is properly incremented. It simply works and there isn't a way for the user to mess it up.

**Summary: This uses a little more computing resources but reduces the amount of possible mistakes a programmer may make when populating a list. It makes the code easier to understand.**

Answer (score 0):

The first pattern only uses a `Node` class, while the second also needs a `LinkedList` class. The first is light-weight, the second is more useful for real, production use. Advantages of the second strategy:

- It does not become bothersome to add many more items. Imagine the first version of the code when you have to create a list with 100 items.
- It is possible to have a `LinkedList` instance that represents an empty list. A `Node` instance represents a list of at least *one* node, unless some special value is used to represent a "sentinel" node.
- It allows methods to alter the `head` or `size` of the list without the caller having to retain that information itself.

You could further extend the `LinkedList` class so the constructor can already take data. There is also an interesting varargs feature in Java, so you can do this:

```
class LinkedList {
    Node head = null, tail = null;
    int size = 0;
    
    LinkedList(int... data) {
        add(data);
    }

    public void add(int... data) {
        for (int value : data) {
            if (head == null) {
                tail = head = new Node(value);
            } else {
                tail = tail.next = new Node(value);
            }
        }
        size += data.length;
    }

    /* ...Other methods... */
}
```

And now you can write:

```
LinkedList lst = new LinkedList(1, 2, 3);
```

or:

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
LinkedList lst = new LinkedList(a);
```

It will be a matter of opinion, but this makes a linked list a pleasure to work with.

Comment: I am not sure I understood the varargs feature. If I am right, it means that someone must write: public String formatWithVarArgs(String... values), when they create the method. Then when you call the method, you can add whatever number of arguments you need, like so: formatWithVarArgs("a", "b", "c", "d"). Is that it? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Indeed, that is how it works. You can pass any number of arguments (or you can pass an array).